# Chrome console/devtools doesn't update css properties: Dynamic stylesheet manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to manipulate CSS properties dynamically via javascript, using the stylesheet methods (deleteRule/removeRule/insertRule). It works nicely but when I check the **Chrome console, it doesn't refresh the new css changes**.

Here you have an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Pz69E/4/
Full screen example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz69E/4/show

It uses a simple external stylesheet file: `body { background-color: black; }`

The script changes to yellow, removing the rule (using deleteRule) and adding a new one (insertRule).

If you check chrome console now over the body, it will have the same first property  `{ background-color: black; }` without updating the new changes. :(

Do you guys know why this behavior?

Thanks!

**EDITED**

For some reason my example was not working in the last 12 hours, now it should work again: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz69E/4/

Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: I think because the existing rule has been saved in the stylesheet file (i.e., style.css)?. this is your current page now: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pz69E/1/show/

Comment: How could I check that body has a yellow 'background-color' then?

Comment: what about this : document.body.style.background ="blue" try this code on console, style will change in http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pz69E/1/show/

Comment: It doesn't work for the complex solution that I'm implementing. I need to use the _proto_ functions of the stylesheet objects to manipulate dynamically the stylesheets. Thanks for the help though!